# Programming Solitaire with Vector. Can't use them in class

Tags: c++, class, methods, vector

I am currently trying to create a Solitaire game.
When I try to use the variable "m_lesCartes", the compiler doesn't let me use it.

This is how I create my class in the ".h".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Carte.h"

using namespace std;

class ColonneCartes {
public:
    ColonneCartes();
    virtual ~ColonneCartes();
    void initColonneCartes(vector<Carte> & p_listeCartes);

private:
    vector<Carte> m_lesCartes;
    int m_nbCartesVisibles;

};
```

When im trying to access "m_lesCartes" in "initColonneCartes" (in the ".cpp"), the compiler is saying "m_lesCartes" is not declared.

```
#include "ColonneCartes.h"

ColonneCartes::ColonneCartes()
{
    this->m_nbCartesVisibles = 0;
}

ColonneCartes::~ColonneCartes()
{
}

void ColonneCartes::initColonneCartes(vector<Carte> & p_listeCartes)
{
    this->m_lesCartes.clear();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i< p_listeCartes.size(); i++)
    {
        this->m_lesCartes.push_back(p_listeCartes[i]);
    }
}
```

If this can help :

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
    g++  -o "Solitaire"  ./Carte.o ./ColonneCartes.o ./ContratException.o ./jeuSolitaire.o   
    ./jeuSolitaire.o: dans la fonction « __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Carte>::new_allocator() »:
    /home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:10: définitions multiples de « ColonneCartes::ColonneCartes() »
    ./ColonneCartes.o:/home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:10: défini pour la première fois ici
    ./jeuSolitaire.o: dans la fonction « __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Carte>::new_allocator() »:
    /home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:10: définitions multiples de « ColonneCartes::ColonneCartes() »
    ./ColonneCartes.o:/home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:10: défini pour la première fois ici
    ./jeuSolitaire.o: dans la fonction « void std::_Construct<Carte, Carte>(Carte*, Carte const&) »:
    /home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:15: définitions multiples de « ColonneCartes::~ColonneCartes() »
    ./ColonneCartes.o:/home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:15: défini pour la première fois ici
    ./jeuSolitaire.o: dans la fonction « void std::_Construct<Carte, Carte>(Carte*, Carte const&) »:
    /home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:15: définitions multiples de « ColonneCartes::~ColonneCartes() »
    ./ColonneCartes.o:/home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:15: défini pour la première fois ici
    ./jeuSolitaire.o: dans la fonction « ColonneCartes::~ColonneCartes() »:
    /home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:15: définitions multiples de « ColonneCartes::~ColonneCartes() »
    ./ColonneCartes.o:/home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:15: défini pour la première fois ici
    ./jeuSolitaire.o: dans la fonction « ColonneCartes::initColonneCartes(std::vector<Carte, std::allocator<Carte> >&) »:
    /home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:21: définitions multiples de « ColonneCartes::initColonneCartes(std::vector<Carte, std::allocator<Carte> >&) »
    ./ColonneCartes.o:/home/etudiant/workspace/Solitaire/Debug/../ColonneCartes.cpp:20: défini pour la première fois ici
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [Solitaire] Erreur 1
```

Comment: Please post the exact compiler error message you're getting

Comment: Would you mind posting the complete class implementation (`.cpp` file) ?

Comment: The compiler errors you posted have nothing to do with the problem you described. The problem is a linking issue, where some symbols are multiply defined... Posting the complete .cpp files involved would help.

Comment: I edited and posted all .cpp and .h.

Comment: The compiler errors you posted have the distinct aroma of either (a) you're declaring *and* implementing the functions in your header, but the implementation is outside the class declaration and not declared as inline, or (b) your `#include`-ing a .cpp file, which is generally always hideous. Judging by your update, i sense the latter. And contrary to your comment that is *not* "all .cpp" files. Ex: the content of `jeuSolitaire.cpp` is clearly missing, unfortunate, as it is the file I harbor suspicions contains the `#include` of a .cpp file, specifically `ColonneCartes.cpp`

Comment: You are completly right WhozCraig, I did write ".cpp" instead of ".h".

The last 2 hours have been complete waste of time..
At least, you are there to save me :)

Comment: Happens more often than you think. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler errors you posted have nothing to do with the problem you described. The problem is a linking issue, where some symbols are multiply defined...

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
    g++  -o "Solitaire"  ./Carte.o ./ColonneCartes.o ./ContratException.o ./jeuSolitaire.o
```

This tells us that the linker combines the object files for the following source files into your executable: Carte.cpp, ColonneCartes.cpp, ContratException.cpp, jeuSolitaire.cpp.
Assuming that you don't have any other definitions in your header files, one of these source files probably defines the same ColonneCartes methods that ColonneCartes defines, most likely by including the .cpp file itself:

```
#include "ColonneCartes.cpp"
```

You should look through your project files for a line like this, and remove it.

Unrelated sidenote: in the spirit of not reinventing the wheel, consider replacing this loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i< p_listeCartes.size(); i++)
{
    this->m_lesCartes.push_back(p_listeCartes[i]);
}
```

with:

```
m_lesCartes.insert(m_lesCartes.end(), p_listeCartes.begin(), p_listeCartes.end());
```

Also unrelated: you already use `m_` to indicate member data, so why use `this->` on top of that ?